# How to add customization options like some card maker websites

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to build a prototype of a website which allows a user to customize the position, colour, tag and name of their business card.
I want to know how can I save the position of any draggable and droppable element in the rails database so that the user can save it for the future

Comment: You should think more like incuding javascript frameworks like canvas js , kinetic js and backbone js .

Answer (score 0):

You should add position field to data model. Also, you can use [acts_as_list gem](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) or implement similar logic by yourself